# Serving a static files with Node.JS server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, nginx

I am building a Node.JS application. It contains several static files (HTML, JS, CSS) and a Socket.IO webserver.

Now I am using Express.JS to serve static files:

```
const server = express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'))) // like that
  .use(sessionMiddleware)
  .use(passport.initialize())
  .use(passport.session())
```

but I think it's an overkill for that. I know that you can set up nginx to serve static files from some folder, but can I do the same on Heroku?

Also, I'm not sure but maybe I should put the static files onto CDN (like Amazon S3) and serve it from there?